# where to find standard windows phone 8 app bar icons?

Tags: icons, windows-phone-8

I want the standard icons for "Add", "Edit", "Settings", "Remove", etc.
I'm sure an official download is out there somewhere.

I'm not looking for fancy customized icons. Just the standard ones are good for me.

Comment: The standard icons are installed with the SDK C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Icons

Comment: Collection of 12000+ icon for Windows Phone at Microsoft Codeplex http://icons.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a whole bunch on [WindowsPhoneGeek.com](http://windowsphonegeek.com/marketplace/Browse?category=icons) that might help you out.

I also found [this collection](https://github.com/Templarian/WindowsIcons) checked into GitHub.

You can also try [Syncfusion Metro Studio](http://windowsphonegeek.com/marketplace/components/Syncfusion-Metro-Studio), which comes with *tons* of icons and lets you export them in XAML or PNG.

I've also been searching for some sort of Microsoft sponsored standard icon set, but I do not believe such a thing exists.

Comment: The MS "standard" ones are somewhat limited but are in the SDK usually at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Icons\